# eBay Merchant Integration Platform (MIP) Error: Enter only the numeric portion of the PostalCode

Tags: java, ebay-api

I'm attempting to upload the `product feed` CSV file to `EBay MIP` server and I keep getting the error: *Enter only the numeric portion of the PostalCode* (error code: *17805*) I've searched everywhere and cannot find a solution.

I'm assuming it is referring to the `postalCode` field in the `location feed` which is set to my 5 digit postal code.

Why do I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Don't suppose you've tried removing spaces from your postal code?

I've found that sometimes an error in the Price feed file isn't picked up until a product feed is pushed etc...

Ultimately, try sending the file that's causing you grief, and as much info as you can (eg responses) to ebay MIP Support: DL-eBay-MIP-L1-Support@ebay.com and mipsupport2@ebay.com too.

They will response and deal with your request in a timely manner.

Make sure you provide your account name info too.